# simple question about $\nabla r$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

In my physics notes, it says

$\nabla r = \underline{e_r} = \frac{\underline{r}}{r}$

and

$\nabla \frac{1}{r} = - \frac{\underline{r}}{r^3} = - \frac{1}{r^2} \underline{e_r}$

---

I don't quite understand why this is?

I know that $\nabla \varphi = (\frac{\delta\varphi}{\delta x},\frac{\delta\varphi}{\delta y},\frac{\delta\varphi}{\delta z})$ but I do not understand the above.

Thanks.

Comment: this notation you use for vectors is unusual. I have seen lower bar for one-forms in 4-dimensional space time calculations where a straight horizontal bar above the variable denotes a 4-vector. But, this notation you use seems out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $r^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$. Taking gradients and using the chain rule,
$$
2r\, \nabla r = 2(x, y, z) = 2\vec{r},\quad\text{or}\quad
\nabla r = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}.
$$
For the second, apply the chain rule and use the preceding identity.

Answer (score 2):

In rectangular coordinates, 
$$(\nabla r)_k = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_k}.$$
Therefore, you must calculate 
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(\sum_k (x_k)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}.$$
You will see that the result is 
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_k} = \frac{x_k}{r}.$$
Consequently 
$$\nabla r = \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}, \, \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}, \, \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} \right) = \left(\frac{x}{r}, \, \frac{y}{r}, \, \frac{z}{r}\right) = \frac{1}{r}(x, \, y, \, z) = \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}.$$
Similarly, you can prove the formula
$$\nabla \left(\frac{1}{r}\right) = -\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}$$
by showing that 
$$\left[\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\right]_k = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right) = -\frac{x_k}{r^3}.$$